# Trying to send Validation Email in django, getting error

Tags: django, django-urls, email-validation

Im trying to send validation email when creating a user in django. It used to work like that but then I did some refactoring on the URLs and used urlpattern = UrlPattern() and urlpattern.register(UserView). That is in the main django project url.py

In the app url.py Im having

```
from django.urls import path
from myapp import backend


urlpatterns = [
    path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>', backend.activate, name='activate')

    ]
```

Here are the project urls

```
from myapp.views import RoomView, UserView
from django_request_mapping import UrlPattern

urlpatterns = UrlPattern()

urlpatterns.register(UserView)
urlpatterns.register(RoomView)
```

where activate is a function in backend_logic, which used to work and send the email to the one from request. However, now Im getting the error

> Reverse for 'activate' not found. 'activate' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: did you use an `app_namespace` in the `urls.py`?

Comment: This is exactly how my app urls.py looks like.  The project urls.py is where Im registering the Views

Comment: but there is something before `urlpatterns = ...`, you at least need to import the `path`, can you share the full file?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem edited the post with the full url files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `python manage.py show_urls` to see is your URL registered properly or not. (It's part of `django-extensions` package, very useful.)

If not, include yours app's urls into your project urls.py.

Example:

```
# project urls.py
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include("shop.urls")),
]
```

```
# app shop/urls.py
from django.urls import path

from shop.views import catalog

urlpatterns = [
    path("", catalog.CatalogueView.as_view(), name="home"),
]
```

Comment: about the URLs you mention here, Im using https://pypi.org/project/django-request-mapping/ - spring-like request mapping for django and my project URLs look as following in the link I'm sending.

Comment: Regarding the python3 manage.py show_urls, I cannot find such command in python3 manage.py help, and Im getting the error: Unknown command: 'show_urls'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.

Comment: Yes, I've checked it before the answer. And I really think, that the problem is you add it directly to project urls.py. So, for your scenario just do:
```
urlpatterns += [
    path("", include("app.urls")),
]
```

below
urlpatterns.register(UserView)
urlpatterns.register(RoomView)

Comment: I'm sorry, `show_urls` is a part of `django-extensions`. I forgot because it's part of my default setup for the last 6 years.

Comment: It worked, I feel stupid now . Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry, I am always happy to help.

Just click the reputation button if possible. :)

Comment: Will check on the usage of show_urls tho!